# ¿por que no me aparece el control web LABEL en visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, label

Este es otro archivo que ya tiene LABEL incluidos pero no se porque a mi no me aparece esa herramienta, no se si es de alguna actualiuzacion de algo o quiza estoy haciendo mal algun proceso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solucion es resetear el Toolbox